# Can I use "be able to" and "can/could" in same sentence?

Tags: grammar

Can I use "can/could" and "be able to" in the same sentence?.

Is it grammatically correct?

Which one is correct?

> She can speak English well.
>
> She is able to speak English well.
>
> She can able to speak English well.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can* and *is able to* both mean the same thing. We can't say *can able to* - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you, Kate Bunting

Comment: @Kate I note you have achieved that curious circumstance of both a tick and a downvote for the same answer. I certainly wouldn't downvote you, but I would have tended to say "...is not idiomatic", rather than "...doesn't make sense". Plenty of things that ARE idiomatic, don't make sense if you think about them e.g. "What's up?"

Answer (score 1):

> She can able to speak English well.

This is wrong because

1. "Can" is a modal verb and modal verbs cannot have a "to" infinitive.

She.....can...............able ........to speak....English well.

.S. modal verb ...adjective...to infinitive...Noun...adverb

2. In the sentence "She can able to speak English well", the adjective "able" is being used as an adverb, and this is not possible. The adverb from **able** is **ably**. "She can ably speak English well." is probably grammatically correct but it is horrible as *ably** and **well* are too close in meaning and the sentence is not idiomatic at all.